# Flask Security - Authentication Token issue

Tags: rest, security, authentication, flask, token

I am doing REST API using Flask/Security, I am able to get authentication token from Flask server, but when I need a way to use the token for subsequent calls.  I am playing with the following code, but unable to get the token parameters into require_api_token.  Any ideas?

```
@app.route("/display")
@require_api_token
def display():
        return "displayed!"

def require_api_token(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def check_token(*args, **kwargs):
        print "checking token..."
        # Check to see if it's in their session
        print session
        if 'api_session_token' not in session:
            jsonify(success=False, data={'login_required': True}, message='Not Authorized!'), 401

        # Otherwise just send them where they wanted to go
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return check_token
```

Comment: What is printed out when you hit the endpoint?

Comment: checking token...
<SecureCookieSession {}>
192.168.56.1 - - [26/Aug/2016 04:37:32] "GET /display HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: also rest client gets "displayed!"